# Split up a binary image using their white boundaries in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to read the values in [this image](http://puu.sh/cU3Nj/b020b60f0b.png) into variables using OCR in MATLAB. I'm having trouble doing so, so I tried to split up this image into smaller parts using the white boundary lines then trying to read it, but I dont know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Clarify on `"trouble doing so"` on reading that image?

Comment: I'm using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18169-optical-character-recognition--ocr-) to do the OCR, and without splitting it up, I get random results. When I crop the image and OCR it, it works much better. Unfortunately I have to do this for a number of images and I cant crop each one individually, so I need to find a way to do it programmatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blocks are always delimited by a completely vertical line, you can find where they are by comparing the original image (here transformed from RGB to grayscale to be a single plane) to a matrix that is made of repeats of the first row of the original image only.  Since the lines are vertical the intensity of the pixels in the first line will be the same throughout.  This generates a binary mask that can be used in conjunction with a quick thresholding to reject those lines that are all black pixels in every row.  Then invert this mask and use `regionprops` to locate the bounding box of each region.  Then you can pull these out and do what you like.

If the lines dividing the blocks of text are not always vertical or constant intensity throughout then there's a bit more work that needs to be done to locate the dividing lines, but nothing that's impossible.  Some example data would be good to have in that case, though.

```
img = imread('http://puu.sh/cU3Nj/b020b60f0b.png');

imshow(img);

imgGray = rgb2gray(img);
imgMatch = imgGray == repmat(imgGray(1,:), size(imgGray, 1), 1);
whiteLines = imgMatch & (imgGray > 0);
boxes = regionprops(~whiteLines, 'BoundingBox');

for k = 1:6
    subplot(3,2,k)
    boxHere = round(boxes(k).BoundingBox);
    imshow(img(boxHere(2):(boxHere(2)+boxHere(4)-1), boxHere(1):(boxHere(1)+boxHere(3)-1), :));
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly What I was looking for. Would you be able to explain what "whiteLines = imgMatch & (imgGray > 0);" and " imshow(img(boxHere(2):(boxHere(2)+boxHere(4)-1), boxHere(1):(boxHere(1)+boxHere(3)-1), :));" does? Thanks.

Comment: So imgMatch is the matrix where the value of the pixel in a given column is the same as the value of the pixel in the first row of that same column.  Then imgGray is the grayscale version of the starting image (which, even though there are no colors, is stored as an RGB image).  (imgGray > 0) is true everywhere that imgGray is above zero, or basically anywhere the original image is not pure black.  Together whiteLines is the matrix that = 1 where both are true - the pixel is equal to the value in the first row and where that value isn't black.

Comment: boxHere is the bounding box of the current region in the for loop.  It is a 1x4 vector where the first two values are the location of the bottom left corner of the box and the final two values the width and height of the box.  What we need is the range of index values covered by the box, which is boxHere(2):(boxHere(2)+boxHere(4)) for the x values and the corresponding ones for the y values.  Addressing the matrix img at these ranges pulls out the values inside the bounding box.  imshow just displays those values as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sum` along the columns of a binary image corresponding to that input image and find peaks from the `sum` values. This is precisely achieved in the code here -

```
img = imread('http://puu.sh/cU3Nj/b020b60f0b.png');
BW = im2bw(img,0.1); %// convert to a binary image with a low threshold

peak_sum_max = 30; %// max of sum of cols to act as threshold to decide as peak
peaks_min_width = 10; %// min distance between peaks i.e. min width of each part 

idx = find( sum(BW,1)>=peak_sum_max );
split_idx = [1 idx( [true diff(idx)>peaks_min_width ] )];
split_imgs = arrayfun(@(x) img(:,split_idx(x):split_idx(x+1)),...
                                             1:numel(split_idx)-1,'Uni',0);

%// Display split images
for iter = 1:numel(split_imgs)
    figure,imshow(split_imgs{iter})
end
```

Please note that the final output `split_imgs` is a cell array with each cell holding image data for each split image.

---

If you would like to have the split images directly without the need for messing with cell arrays, after you have `split_idx`, you can do this -

```
%// Get and display split images
for iter = 1:numel(split_idx)-1
    split_img = img(:,split_idx(iter):split_idx(iter+1));
    figure,imshow(split_img)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a built-in `ocr` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.